# How to return a new array of objects that contains merged data from source and target?

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, merge

I want to compare an `oldItems` array of objects and if `id` matches the `id` in my `updatedItems` array of objects, I want to update the object, copying over the property from `oldItems` if there is no value in `updatedItems` for that key or if that property is not defined, and replacing the `oldItems` object property with the `updatedItems` object property if there IS a value. I want to store all the changes in a `result` variable and log `result` to the console.
The `result` variable should contain exactly an object with `id: 1`, the new sandwich name, and the old price, as well as `id: 2` with the new price and the new name.

```
const oldItems = [
    {
        id: 0,
        name: "peanut butter sandwich",
        price: 3
    },
    {
        id: 1,
        name: "cheese sandwich",
        price: 4
    }, 
    {
        id: 2,
        name: "chicken sandwich",
        price: 6
    }
]

const updatedItems = 
    [{
        id: 1,
        name: "grilled cheese sandwich"
    }, {
        id: 2,
        price: 5,
        name: "chicken and waffles sandwich"
    }]
```

I tried:

```
let result = oldItems.map((item, i) => Object.assign({}, item, updatedItems[i]));  
console.log(result);
```

Comment: Loop through `updatedItems`. For each item, use `find()` to search for the `oldItems` with the same ID. Then merge the objects with `{...oldItem, ...newItem}`.

Comment: What have you tried? we're here to help debug not solve the entire problem for you

Comment: @Barmar would you be so kind as to write the code? I have tried so many versions and I always get duplicates or missing information. I am new to this forum and new to coding.

Comment: @Sarah one thing I tried is: ```let result = oldItems.map((item, i) => Object.assign({}, item, updatedItems[i]));

console.log(result);```

Comment: @GabrielHenton I recommend you provide an additional example of the objects you expect to support your description.

Comment: Your code assumes that both arrays have the corresponding items at the same index. Also, why are you looping over `oldItems`? I thought you wanted the results to be based on `updatedItems`.

Comment: @Barmar, it's super important that I loop over both and compare because I want to make sure any properties that don't exist in the new but exist in the old are carried over to the result. If no price change is specified, the old one remains, and is not erased, and so forth.

Comment: That's what `find()` is for. It loops over the other array to find the same ID.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not completely certain of your use-case, but this will produce the `result` you describe.

```js
oldItems.map(o => {
    const update = updatedItems.find(u => u.id === o.id);
    if (update) return {
        ...o,
        ...update
    }

}).filter(x => x)
```

result :

```js
[
  { id: 1, name: 'grilled cheese sandwich', price: 4 },    
  { id: 2, name: 'chicken and waffles sandwich', price: 5 }
]
```

Answer (score 0):

First, your code maps over the wrong array, you should be mapping `updatedItems`.

Second, you can't use the same `i` for both arrays, since the items with the same `id` are not at the same indexes. Use `find()` to search the array for the `id`.

In ES6 you can use `...` to merge objects instead of `Object.assign()`.

```js
const oldItems = [{
    id: 0,
    name: "peanut butter sandwich",
    price: 3
  },
  {
    id: 1,
    name: "cheese sandwich",
    price: 4
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    name: "chicken sandwich",
    price: 6
  }
];

const updatedItems = [{
  id: 1,
  name: "grilled cheese sandwich"
}, {
  id: 2,
  price: 5,
  name: "chicken and waffles sandwich"
}];

let result = updatedItems.map((item) => ({
  ...oldItems.find(el => el.id == item.id),
  ...item
}));
console.log(result);
```

Comment: @Barmer THANK YOU. This solution worked. It makes sense that I should be mapping over ```updatedItems``` instead.